# Dynamic Values Generation in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get my corresponding search result values based on Zipcode values by using HTML form fields.

HTML:

```
<p>Zip Code:
    <input type="text" id="zip" pattern="\d{5}" maxlength="5" name="zip" required="required" />
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#tfnewsearch").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var results = $("#resultContainer");
    var text = $("#search").val();
    results.empty();
    $.get("file:///C:/Users/test/Desktop/Search1.html", function(data) {
        results.append($(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Can i have any solution for this ? Can this be done by using get and post values?

Thank You

Comment: Add some code in question

Comment: <p>Zip Code:
        <input type="text" id="zip" pattern="\d{5}" maxlength="5" name="zip" required="required" />
    </p>
   I just want to know how can I can make my logic?                                    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tfnewsearch").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var results = $("#resultContainer");
        var text = $("#search").val();
        results.empty();
        $.get("file:///C:/Users/test/Desktop/Search1.html", function(data) {
            results.append($(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")"));
        });
    });
</script>